# Create a custom credential provider which can access web camera during session 0

Tags: windows, webcam-capture, credential-providers

Till now, I was under the impression that during logon, webcamera and microphone cannot be accessed in session 0. I saw an application https://da.keylemon.com/home do that. Need help in understanding how to access the webcamera during logon?